# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=3; regionLength=2

Tags: java, android-studio

can anyone help me with this??

```
11-15 14:37:17.325 18731-18731/com.myaplication.marbelmoneymanager E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.myaplication.marbelmoneymanager, PID: 18731
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myaplication.marbelmoneymanager/com.myaplication.marbelmoneymanager.Income.NewIncomeActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=3; regionLength=2
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=3; regionLength=2
     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:588)
     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1475)
     at com.myaplication.marbelmoneymanager.Income.NewIncomeActivity.onCreate(NewIncomeActivity.java:102)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5484)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i think the problem lie in here this code

```
this.xday = this.tgl.substring(3, 5);
```

cause the log cat bring me to here

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newincome);
        this.spin = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinCategory));
        this.txtAmount = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAmount));
        this.txtDetail = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDetail));
        this.btnEdit = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCat));
        Bundle localBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        this.ciDS = new CategoryInDataSource(this);
        this.ciDS.open();
        this.iDS = new IncomeDataSource(this);
        this.iDS.open();
        loadSpinnerData();
        if (localBundle != null)
        {
            this.txtAmount.setText(localBundle.getString("jumlah"));
            this.txtDetail.setText(localBundle.getString("ket"));
            this.tgl = localBundle.getString("temp");
            this.cat = localBundle.getString("cat");
            this.minDate = localBundle.getString("min");
        }
        this.xday = this.tgl.substring(3, 5);
        this.xmonth = this.tgl.substring(0, 2);
        this.xyear = this.tgl.substring(7, 11);
        this.waktu = (this.xyear + "-" + this.xmonth + "-" + this.xday + " 00:00:00");
        this.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View paramView)
            {
                NewIncomeActivity.this.intent = new Intent(NewIncomeActivity.this, IncomeCategoryActivity.class);
                NewIncomeActivity.this.intent.putExtra("jumlah", NewIncomeActivity.this.txtAmount.getText().toString());
                NewIncomeActivity.this.intent.putExtra("ket", NewIncomeActivity.this.txtDetail.getText().toString());
                NewIncomeActivity.this.intent.putExtra("temp", NewIncomeActivity.this.tgl);
                NewIncomeActivity.this.intent.putExtra("min", NewIncomeActivity.this.minDate);
                NewIncomeActivity.this.intent.putExtra("cat", NewIncomeActivity.this.cat);
                NewIncomeActivity.this.startActivity(NewIncomeActivity.this.intent);
                NewIncomeActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `substring(3, 5)` on an empty String.

Comment: That's quite a long stacktrace and code sample. Also, did you look at `NewIncomeActivity.java` line 102? It says where the exception occurred in the stacktrace.

Comment: Scott M. : That's line belong to substring(3, 5)

Comment: Frank N. Stein It still give me an error, it says java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that localBundle.getString("temp"); is returning nothing cause the error says the string in question's length is 0. I'd trace that to make sure it is returning what you want it too.

Comment: yeah i have a problem in there before but i wrapping it in try catch and it don't get error anymore, but my problem lie when i'm using datepicker , click my chosen date and click my choose button (nothing happen) thats why thisis my other code in Incomeactivity using datepicker  http://prntscr.com/92xktf